# How do I add a method to a UIButton in a prototype cell?

Tags: uitableview, prototype

Hi am creating a table with two prototype cells. The button "Cell One" is connected to the method *btnCellOneTouched* and button "Cell Two" is connected to *btnCellTwoTouched*. The button in each prototype cell has tag 0 and the textfield has tag 1.

Each prototype cell has its own identifier - *cellOne* and *cellTwo* respectively. This is the code in my **.m** file. The variables are all correct and give no error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    intNumRows = 0;
    numSections = 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    return numSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    return intNumRows;
}

- (void)displayRowNum:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", btn.tag);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellType];
    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCellType];

    [(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:0] addTarget:self action:@selector(displayRowNum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)btnCellOneTouched:(id)sender
{
    strCellType = @"cellOne";
    intLastRow = [tblMain numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:intLastRow inSection:0];
    intNumRows++;
    [tblMain insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
- (IBAction)btnCellTwoTouched:(id)sender
{
    strCellType = @"cellTwo";
    intLastRow = [tblMain numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:intLastRow inSection:0];
    intNumRows++;
    [tblMain insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

I am getting an error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90638e0'** when i run the program.

What is wrong with the way I am assigning a method to the button in the cell created at runtime?

If I comment out the line where I add the target, it works fine.

This one has me flummoxed for a while. Please help.

Thanks,
Anjaan.

Comment: I figured this out myself. I connected the *Touch Up Inside* event in the "Sent Events" section of the Connections Inspector to the method displayRowNum and this works.

Comment: y u cant u give direct iboutlet in that custam cell with that action